# Consequence of Löwenheim-Skolem theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory, metalogic

I am trying to understand the following consequence of Löwenheim-Skolems theorem:

> Let ∑ be a set of sentences in a countable language. If ∑ has any
> model, then it has a countable model.

I do not really understand if it means that ∑ has a countable model but also can have non-countable models or if it **only** can have a countable model/models? I appreciate if anyone would help me clarify this, thanks in advance!

Comment: it means that if $\Sigma$ has a model, then at least one of the models of $\Sigma$ is countable, the rest may or may not be countable.

Comment: It means the former: it must have at least one countable model, but it can have uncountable models. And in fact if it has an infinite model, it has models of all infinite cardinalities.

Comment: @Zuhair Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you Brian for your clarification!

Comment: @idlatva: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been answered in the comments, but to make things complete let me explain why. I think Brian's statement phrases this very well:

> If $\Sigma$ has a model, it must have at least one countable model. If it has an infinite model, it has models of all infinite cardinalities.

Here we take countable to mean "finite or countably infinite".

If $\Sigma$ has a finite model, then that is directly the countable model we were looking for. If $\Sigma$ has an infinite model $M$ we will need to produce a countable model. In fact, we will show that we can produce a model of cardinality $\kappa$ for any infinite $\kappa$, just as in Brian's improved claim.  By compactness can find  an elementary extension $M'$, so $M \preceq M'$, such that $|M'| \geq \kappa$. This is sometimes also called "upwards Löwenheim-Skolem", but it really is a simple argument where you just add $\kappa$ many new constant symbols and declare them to be distinct. Now pick any subset $A \subseteq M'$ with $|A| = \kappa$, then by the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem there is some $N$ with $A \subseteq N \preceq M'$ such that $|N| = |A| + |\Sigma| + \aleph_0$. Since $|A| = \kappa \geq \aleph_0$ and $|\Sigma| = \aleph_0$ we get $|N| = \kappa$. So $N$ is our model of cardinality $\kappa$.

So in fact this shows that the only way that $\Sigma$ can only have countable models is if it has only finite models. Any theory with infinite models will have arbitrarily large infinite models.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and clarification, this made it very clear and easy for me to understand!

Comment: Happy to hear! If your question is fully answered, can you accept the answer? That way other users can see that the question has an answer as well.

Comment: Yes of course! I will do that!